# Empty upgrade array

Tags: networking, socket.io

I'm connecting to this server outside my local machine which i don't have access to apart from being a regular user and in the request headers `Origin: websocket` is present but the first message in dev tools that the browser client receives is `0{"sid":"43fcc6c1-023b-437e-8155-0b6e33fbe0cd","upgrades":[],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":60000}`
...Yes an emtpy upgrade array and the wss url is like this `wss://domingo.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket`... what is up with this please?